# cumsum() over several columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I want to create the following dataframe:

```
Index       A        B        C
 a          0        0        0
 b          1       10        0
 c         -1        0      -10
 d          1       20        0
 e          0        0        0
 f         -1        0      -20
 g          0        0        0
 h          1       15        0
 i         -1        0      -15
```

`A` and `B` are given. `C` shall be generated via a function and without iteration. Possibly in this fashion:

```
def generate_C():
    C = np.where(A == -1, << here prior value from B * -1 >>, 0)
    df['C] = C
    return df
```

I tried via cumsum() over columns `B` and `C` but did not come far. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Your question is interesting. However I do not understand the connection to `cumsum`.

Comment: I think you can add more values to your dataframe, because it is not clear why is necessary use `cumsum`.

Comment: I thought about using cumsum() because the cumsum() over B and C should result in the remaining positive value from column B. For example in row c: cumsum() over B and C (from rows a to b) is +10. In Excel I would use something like this =IF(A7=-1;SUM($B$2:C6)*-1;0).

Comment: I still dont understand. Is possible add more value in column `B` ?

Comment: @jezrael, an alternative solution would certainly be welcome. This is only a part of a larger dataframe where all comumns are generated via the function. Thus also generation of  C should be part in function. EDIT: added some more rows

Comment: Yes, sure. I think deeply testing is the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df.C = (df.B.replace(0, np.nan).ffill().shift() * (df.A == -1) * -1).fillna(0)
```

---

confirmed jezrael's suggestion:

```
df.C = (df.B.replace(0, np.nan).ffill() * (df.A == -1) * -1).fillna(0)
```

works just as well.  Since we are forward filling, the shift became unnecessary.

confirmed ColonelBeauvel's suggestion:

```
df.C = np.where(df.A==-1, -df.B.replace(0, method='ffill').shift(), 0)
```

Also works and would be my vote as the answer of choice had it been posted as an answer and actually my choice.

Comment: I think `shift` can be omit `(df.B.replace(0, np.nan).ffill() * (df.A == -1) * -1).fillna(0)`

Comment: or maybe more readable for OP: `np.where(df.A==-1, -df.B.replace(0, method='ffill').shift(), 0)` . Instead of putting NA, it's neater to say, ' want to fill forward 0 values. As well as where which is quite explicit.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel that sounds like an answer waiting to happen.  I didn't know you could pass `method='ffill'` to `replace`.  That is cool!

Comment: I think this is the most pythonic answer with a one-liner. But it's not SO different from yours so I will not post it.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, the one-liner is quite intriguing. I still have to test in how far generation of column A and all other columns  (not all shown) are affected by shift and ffill. I have also had some issues with using shift() in functions and vectorised design in past issues.

Comment: I decided for this solution from @ColonelBeauvel due to the one-line design and the fact that I learned some new application of already known functions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
df.loc[df.A==-1, 'C'] = (-df.loc[df.A==1, 'B']).values
df.C.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print (df)
       A   B    C   
Index                 
a      0   0   0.0
b      1  10   0.0
c     -1   0 -10.0
d      1  20   0.0
e      0   0   0.0
f     -1   0 -20.0
```

Comment: This looks as close as possible to the [`numpy` solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37608625/1170207) I posted, and apparently it's the most readable way to do it in `pandas`. I think if someone insists on using pure `pandas`, this should be the preferred way to do it.

Comment: Thank you. I think all solution are very nice.

Comment: Maybe you could edit the answer so that it doesn't generate the column `C2` instead of `C`. At first glance I was a little bit surprised that the method needed a "helper" column, but after reading the code it was apparent that it is not the case.

Comment: @jezrael, this solution looks like coming close to what I am looking for. need to check how to incorprate that into the function and see if generation of column A is affected (because it's indirectly dependent on the outcomes from C, I did not mention this earlier because I was not expecting my question leading to rather complex solutions)

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to do in `numpy`, but I have yet to find a way to find a way to do it directly in `pandas`, because apparently `pandas` somehow ignores the fancy indexing:

```
def generate_C(df, inplace=False):
    import numpy

    if not inplace:
        df = df.copy()

    A, B = df.values.T
    C = numpy.zeros_like(A)
    C[A==-1] = -B[A==1]
    df['C'] = C

    return df
```

---

EDIT:

I found a way to to it with pure `pandas`:

```
def generate_C(df, inplace=False):
    if not inplace:
        df = df.copy()

    df['C'] = (-df.B[df.A==1]).reindex(df.A[df.A==-1].index,method='pad')
    df['C'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

    return df
```